# How to correctly use separators in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

Consider the following code in OCamel:

```
let rodrigue="The cid" ; let diegue="cid's father"
```

this gives a syntax error on tryOcaml. What is wrong? It seems to work when I removed the ; Please help.

Also,
rodrigue.[4] <- 'c' gives unknown constructor error. Does this mean that we can't use <- ? as rodrigue.[4] is immutable or there is a function to change a character in a string?

What does ; do ?
I tried `4=4 ;6=5`, it gave a value of bool= false.

is `4=4` an expression or a statement?

what about `let x=5`?

So `let x=8 let y=9` executes both statements but $4=4 ; 5=6$ only evaluate the last expression?

What is the difference between an expression and a statement?

What is toplevel? What is the difference between toplevel and normal OCamel expression?

Comment: You might want to read [ask] and probably also the [tour]. You're expected to do some research on your own, like reading documentation and basic tutorials and to do a search to check whether the question has been asked before. You should also ask only one question per post. I count eight here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two places where you can use `let` in OCaml. At the top level of a module you can have this:

```
let pattern = expression
```

A module is, in essence, a collection of named values, and this form of `let` is the way of defining a name and its value.

On the other hand, there is an OCaml expression that looks like this:

```
let pattern = expression1 in expression2
```

This is, in essence, a way of defining local variables for use in `expression2`.

Your code with the `;` doesn't work as either of these forms. A `;` is used to combine two expressions into a single expression. But `let pattern = value` is not an expression. It has the form of a top-level declaration of a module.

The reason it works when you remove the `;` is that you then have *two* top-level declarations. That will work as long as the code appears at the top level of a module. In this case, it defines the names `rodrigue` and `diegue` as named values of the module.

Other answers:

In recent versions of OCaml, strings are not mutable. You need to use the `bytes` type if you need mutability. As part of this change the `string.[...] <- ...` notation became obsolete. You should use `Bytes.set` instead.

```
# let mystring = "abc";;
val mystring : string = "abc"
# let mybytes = Bytes.of_string "abc";;
val mybytes : bytes = Bytes.of_string "abc"
# mystring.[0] <- 'b';;
Warning 3: deprecated: String.set
Use Bytes.set instead.
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was 
            expected of type bytes
# Bytes.set mybytes 0 'b';;
- : unit = ()
# mybytes;;
- : bytes = Bytes.of_string "bbc"
```

OCaml doesn't really have statements. In places where you would have a statement in some other languages, you have an expression of type `unit`. For example, the `for` statement in OCaml is actually an expression with `unit` type.

```
# for x = 1 to 1 do () done = ();;
- : bool = true
```

From this point of view, then, `4 = 4` is an expression because it has type `bool` (and not `unit`).

So then `let x = 5` is neither an expression nor a statement (which is just a kind of expression). As I pointed out above, this has the form of a top-level module declaration. Hence, it can only appear at the top of a module.

In contrast, `let x = 5 in x + 2` is an expression with the value 7.

The name `toplevel` is what OCaml veterans call the read-eval-print loop of OCaml. In other words, it's a name for the OCaml interpreter.

In my answers above I'm using "top level" to mean the outermost syntactic nesting level of a module. It's not the same as the toplevel (the OCaml interpreter).